# No locally installed toolchains match mac

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I have a flutter application. Everything was working fine till I included the social_share package, and it started to crash, and interestingly enough, it started to crash in the packages that didn't have problems before. Now whenever I try to run on android, I get this issue

```
Execution failed for task ':audioplayers_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Error while evaluating property 'javaCompiler' of task ':audioplayers_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':audioplayers_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'javaCompiler'.
      > No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=8, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}.
         > No locally installed toolchains match (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection) and toolchain download repositories have not been configured (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories).
```

Here is my project-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        javaCompiler = javaToolchains.compilerFor {
            languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

This is an app-level build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34 //localProperties.getProperty("flutter.compileSdkVersion")
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rlabs.wordera"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))

    // Add the dependency for the Firebase Authentication library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")

    // Also add the dependency for the Google Play services library and specify its version
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0")
}
```

I reinstalled java, Android Studio, I asked chat-gpt, codepilot and bard, nothing help haha. What is the issue here?